# SublimeLinter with syntax check for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-12.04

I've just installed https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter 
and was wondering : it possible by default to switch  checking ruby ?
they write that Ruby - syntax checking via `ruby -wc` but how it's to be called?
And are there any rails specific addons? didn't find other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not *quite* sure what you're asking ... but if you're looking to change SublimeLinter so that it runs something other than `ruby -wc`, then you can edit line 10 in the file `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules/ruby.py`.

For example, you can take these steps to have SublimeLinter use your gemset's ruby:

- Hold the option key down
- Click the `Go` menu in Finder
- Select `Library`
- Navigate into `Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeLinter/sublimelinter/modules`
- Open the file `ruby.py` in Sublime Text 2
- Change line 10 from `'executable': 'ruby',` to `'executable': '/Users/YOUR-USER-NAME/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby',`
- Restart Sublime Text 2

**Update:**

I just found out an easier way to accomplish this...

You can change the SublimeLinter settings to have SublimeLinter use your gemset's ruby by opening the `Sublime Text 2` menu, going into Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter, and selecting `Settings - User`. Add this text to the file, save it, and restart Sublime Text 2:

```
{
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    {
        "ruby": "rvm-auto-ruby"
    }
}
```